# get the file URI of an ImageItem

Tags: 8, files

How can I get the file URI of a `Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ImageItem` instance?

I get the field value with `$node_entity->get('field_image')[0]` but I don't know how to get the file URI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
$image_item->entity->getFileUri()
```